# Erlang equivalent to Parsec library

Tags: haskell, erlang, parsec

Is there an **Erlang** library equivalent to **Parsec** or **attoparsec** (Written with Haskell) ?

Comment: Depends on what you're looking for, but generally this is where I look first: http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/parsetools/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, written in Erlang.

It's called [Parsec Erlang](https://bitbucket.org/dmercer/parsec-erlang/src).

More Parsec clones in other languages can be found [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsec#Parsec_clones_in_other_languages).